# How to access data from a HashMap that is a Text type?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've encountered a minor issue:

I have A Method that add values to  HashMap as follow:

```
Map<Text,Text> kv =new HashMap<Text,Text>();
kv.put(new Text(0),new Text(0));
kv.put(new Text(1),new Text(1));
```

PS: Text is a type from MapReduce framework.

When I try to access the data as follow from MapReduce job:

```
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<Text, Text> entry : result.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() + ","+ entry.getValue());
    }
```

I was getting results as follow:

```
1,1
1,1
```

But When I tried the same thing in standard Java, I was getting the result as expected:

```
0,0
1,1
```

Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: what happened if you do this: `Text t1 = new Text(0); Text t2 = new Text(1); System.out.println(t1 + "," + t2)` What will be the output

Comment: @Nami, I tried that, but it still output 1,1 1,1. But when I changed the type to String, it prints correctly on MapReduce framework. I'm not sure why it behaves differently(incorrectly) with the Text type.